# Apple distribution failed using codemagic

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I am deploying my app for the first time on Apple, and since I do not have a mac I am using CodeMagic.
All the app building steps worked fine, but at the last step, App Store Connect distribution, it failed.
[image: Failed Logs]

The build is not visible on Apple Connect; instead, I am seeing this
[image: Apple Connect Screen]

Note - I dont see the build in TestFlight also

Comment: Look for an email from Apple telling you there was an issue with your build

Comment: I received it but they were just warning as per the emaill

Comment: Warning what?  That you need to provide export compliance information? Are you sure that your CFBundleVersion is 1.0?

Comment: "ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist"

"Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them:"

Comment: Yepp. This warning needs to be fixed. Or the build is not visible. I have encountered this. Maybe apple team need to change the criteria, but it needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, after fixing the "warning". My build is visible, thanks

Comment: @AbhishekDoshi post your comment please as an answer. In this case it will be helpful for other users and easier to find the solution